# Skipping variable number of C-style comment lines when using pandas read_table

Tags: python, pandas

The pandas `read_table()` function enables us to read `*.tab` file and the parameter `skiprow` provides flexible ways to retrieve the data. However, I'm in trouble when I need to read `*.tab` file in a loop but the number of the rows need to skip is random. For example, the contents need to skip are started with  `/*` and ended with `*/` , such as:

```
/*
... 
The number of rows need to skip is random
...
*/
```

So how do I find the line of the `*/` and then use the parameter `skiprow`?

Comment: It's misleading to call them "random", because they're not, they just have a syntax that the pandas parser doesn't currently handle. *"Skip a variable number of C-style comment lines"* would be more accurate. Anyway whenever the pandas parser can't handle something, which is often, you roll up your sleeves and code a base Python fix.

Comment: When you say *`For example, the contents need to skip start with /* and end with */ `*, is that just one example (of many) and you want to write a generalized regex-based header parser? Or do you only want to parse C-style comments? Anyway, we can do both. By the way, this is only a subset of C-style comments, because the `*/` close can occur anywhere on a row, not just on its own separate row as the only characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consume rows until the current row starts with `'*/'`:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for row in fp:
        if row.startswith('*/'):
            df = pd.read_table(fp)
```

Comment: A useful enhance would be to print *"INFO: Skipped {n} lines of C-style comment header"*.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean, do I need to add a command in the line bolow with open ('data.txt') as fp: ? Please be more careful, thank you.

Comment: Yongwu, I'm suggesting to @Corralien that they add code that counts the header lines, then print *"INFO: Skipped {n} lines of C-style comment header"*. It's not complicated.